# Vagrant crashes on WSL

Tags: virtual-machine, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vagrant, wsl2

I am trying to run a simple VM in my WSL using vagrant.
I am using Ubuntu 22.04 on WSL2 with vagrant version 2.2.19.
On my windows (with VirtualBox 6.1.36) i have a simple directory which contains the VagrantFile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64"
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
   vb.customize [ "modifyvm", :id, "--uartmode1", "disconnected" ]
  end
end
```

I have already set

```
$ export VAGRANT_WSL_ENABLE_WINDOWS_ACCESS="1"
export PATH="$PATH:/mnt/c/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox"
```

When i try to run vagrant up on the WSL i get the following timeout error:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'ubuntu/bionic64'...

==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/bionic64' version '20220902.0.0' is up to date...
==> default: A newer version of the box 'ubuntu/bionic64' for provider 'virtualbox' is
==> default: available! You currently have version '20220902.0.0'. The latest is version
==> default: '20220916.0.0'. Run `vagrant box update` to update.
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: exmaple1_default_1663773206124_15632
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 172.21.80.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key

Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

I'm stuck with this problem for a couple of days now, i have already tried [this link](https://terryl.in/en/vagrant-up-hangs/) and [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38463579/vagrant-hangs-at-ssh-auth-method-private-key) but nothing works....